# What is a Polonix Wallet address?

Tags: poloniex

I sent some ether to Poloniex
`https://etherscan.io/address/0x2b85d38c4c3d9422f75156ea36f479ab26a98faa`
As you can see in `etherscan.io`, there are 2 income transfers for this address.
This is for my Polonix account. After that, I tried to do withdraw some ether and checked the transaction.
`https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5f32f8ca905f975cf8c2977b3f3cefcf5f0ad6b3f7c704d8b761e2671f1034d8`
This is my withdraw transaction. But from address is `"Poloniex Wallet"`.
What is `"Poloniex Wallet"`?
Polonix has their pool address?
If they have pool address, how can they have my ether?

I also checked this `Poloniex Wallet` in Etherscan.
`https://etherscan.io/address/0x32be343b94f860124dc4fee278fdcbd38c102d88`
But there is no any income transfers?
It is weird.

Such this problem is also showing in Okex. I did withdraw to    `0xf4A3D01Dc620687301b678b437913d57CA511bf9`.
But `from` address is not my account. It says `from` address is `0x236F9F97e0E62388479bf9E5BA4889e46B0273C3` but my `Okex` address is `0x9CdAEFeE6fAe05B98A4a1492E2596b96712fB8A5`.

How can I understand this problem?
Please let me be clear about this problem.

Comment: With exchanges you might not have constant address. Sometimes, the funds are kept together in different accounts, sometimes each transactions use separate account. Depends on how exchanges implement it. There might be fund account and exchange account.

Comment: Well,, But it is showing as a `poloniexwallet` when someone made a withdraw.
His exchange wallet and my one can be same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchanges use their own wallets to hold the ethereum backed by them. You don't have an "exchange account" in the sense that there's a dedicated ethereum address at each exchange for only your funds to sit in. Instead, exchanges move funds around all the time for the purposes of moving things from hot storage into cold storage or vice versa. This allows them to mitigate damage from being broken into -- the storage separation is necessary to isolate money and keep it out of the hands of would-be hackers.

You deposited funds into Poloniex through a deposit address linked to your account. When they received it, they credited you for that amount deposited, but that doesn't mean that you get the "same ether" back when you withdraw from them. Instead, you get whatever their hot wallet is sending you money. This is principally why you shouldn't store money in exchanges. The amount that sits on your account is only a promise that there is some ether that can be sent to you. It isn't that there's a dedicated account for you sitting there to use.

There aren't any incoming transactions in their wallet because the wallet isn't a wallet contract. This is called an [EOA](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8923/accounts-cant-display-incoming-transactions).

Comment: I am  creating wallet for new exchange site.
How can I create the account like "Poloniex wallet" `(0x32Be343B94f860124dC4fEe278FDCBD38C102D88)`?
And do I need to resend ethers that I received from others?
Please help me for this problems